# Export Apex application

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

When I export my apex application and import into the same schema so all the interactive report Lov's are disappear from the "Named List of Values" column in interactive report.

Please help me out I don't know why it happening.

Thanks,
Anky

Comment: I've encountered this, but in my case it was quickest just to recreate the LOVs. This might help: https://community.oracle.com/message/9484188

Comment: Can you supply APEX version?

Comment: I am using Apex 4.0. Each and every time when i export the application the same problem raise.

Comment: Thanks Bacs. Problem has been resolved with the help of your link.